# Storyboard and Tabbar with background image

Tags: ios, storyboard, background-image, tabbar

I am creating a Tabbar with navigations using storyboard. With storybaord, i am allowed to create tabs and pick images for each tab. Also storyboard allows me to change the background of the tabbar.

Now, i need to customize the background of tabbar and selected item background ( using image).

Searching on how to customize tabbar provides suggestion like adding the background image with help of code in viewdid load event.

Is it not possible directly from storyboard to provide background image and selectedbackground image for Tabbar, so all navigation and designing is done by drag-drop actions.

Comment: If you click on the tab bar and click on one of the options on the right pane, it should have a drop down for you to select the background image of the tabbar

Comment: the background option doesn't allow to select any image.. it picks color only.